# how to read a csv file line by line having line break and coma in fields

Tags: java, file-handling

I have to read a csv file line by line and change line break (alt+enter that is \n\r) with space and comas out side of fields with Ctrl+A (\001). As I try this with reading Buffered Reader, it takes line from \n and not interpret \n\r as non line break character. How can I handle this. I have to done this in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the entire file into a String variable and then use `String.replaceAll()` to replace the characters as you want:-

```
    File file = new File("abc.csv");
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    fis.read(data);
    fis.close();
    String str = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

And then replace characters in the String:-

```
str = str.replaceAll("\r\n", " ");
str = str.replaceAll("[,]", ";");
System.out.println(str);
```

Then you can create a new file or overwrite the existing file using the new String

Comment: Thanks for replying, is there any CSVReader library , which handle this type of things internally.

Comment: There are many csv reader libraries available like [CSVParser from Apache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html) , But you will have to google out and find if they have capability to handle out such implementations. I mostly use my own custom java code to parse CSVs. Also I think your requirement more specifically targets String/File manipulation rather than focussing on CSVs.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean "\r\n", not "\n\r". Usually windows-based programs generate "\r\n" while linux-based programs use "\n".

The buffered reader normally uses the global "line.separator" setting that should be set specifically for your system.

On a sidenote: it is usually interesting to use frameworks for parsing instead of doing actual line reads because there are a lot of edge cases (like this one) that a framework usually covers.

Comment: Actually few fields contains test data submited by user, which is alt+enter, so what does it As I know is \n\r (but not confirm), Could you please confirm this will be \n\r or r\n. All the things are at linux system