# How to Read csv file with line breaks when "\r\n" does not work

Tags: java, replaceall

I am new to Java and have been reading Java docs and other threads ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373120/how-to-read-a-csv-file-line-by-line-having-line-break-and-coma-in-fields) ,[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056834/replace-n-and-r-n-with-br-in-java)) but couldn't make it work.

Basically my csv file has few records which read like this

```
How are
you
```

so I want my code to read it as one line

```
How are you
```

My code looks like this:

```
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(csv),"utf-8"));

    while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String lines = line.replaceAll("\r\n", " ");
        System.out.println(lines);
```

Manually, when I pressed backspace at `you`it goes back with `are`and I pressed space. Then it was fine. But I have a big csv file with 29k records. There must be a way through which I can fix this. Can you please point me towards the direction? Thank you.

[Edit]

This is how it appears.

```
Fav: Beaver tails.
Least fav: HST not included in prices.
```

Edit 2:

```
-3166,1054,CF ,5992841,15:37.5,en,13007,12,12,Comments: Favorite and/or least favorite things,0,"Cafe Fun
-Least favourite - cabs"
```

"Cafe Fun Least Favourite - cabs" should be on the same line.

Comment: It's not working for all of them? or just for few?

Comment: Processing CSV correctly is tricky, especially when dealing with quotes fields.  Don't write your own CSV reader, use one of the existing, _debugged_ CSV libraries.

Comment: @JimGarrison can you please suggest few? I'll google too.

Comment: Look up OpenCSV or Apache Commons CSV

Comment: Can you paste a peice that would actually be found in your file, eg. "is this\r\na record", but is "this"\r\n"two records" ?

Comment: I don't see any comma's. I also don't see how this relates to newlines being part of the same record.

Comment: @matt where I open the csv file in excel at this specific cell, I have to extend the cell read it because it is one step down.If I am using sublime text reader, then it is showing a new line

Comment: Jim Garrison has the correct idea.  I've had good results using Apache Commons CSV.  Never tried OpenCSV.  Please ignore (or downvote) any answers here that don't use a CSV library - you shouldn't be re-inventing wheels.

Comment: I mean you need to show the actual csv you want to parse. Not the table that you see in excel. If you have some subset of csv that you want to parse, then *maybe* you can get away with what you're doing. From the sounds of it though, you should get a csv reader. Do you have cells like "Hey, I am a csv cell with a comma."

Comment: @matt I have cells like that. I am going to take a crack at Apache Commons csv and give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

`readLine()` will return the next line in the file, without the line separator. So on the first iteration of your loop, `lines` is `"How are"` and on the second iteration, `lines` is `"you"`. Neither of these contain `"\r\n"`, so your calls to `replaceAll(...)` just return the same string.

Then, `System.out.println(...)` prints the text *with a line separator appended*, so you get back to what you started with.

You can collect all the lines into a list:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(csv);
```

and then concatenate them using `String.join(...)`:

```
String allLines = String.join(" ", lines);
```

Comment: @Sweeper In that case, yes. I read "my file has few records" as meaning that the file had only a few lines.

Comment: @Sweeper "readLine" could load the whole file into memory and cause an out of memory error too.

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader.readLine()` doesn't read the newline, so your String `lines` does't have a brake.
You only print a newline with `System.out.println(lines);` change it to `System.out.print(lines);` and invoke `System.out.println();` after the while-loop.

```
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(csv),"utf-8"));

while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.print(line);
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

To start the csv (as the name implies) are files separated by commas, not by spaces. But forgetting that, the readLine only reads the line where the "pointer" is, and in that case "you" is in another line than "How are". I think that's where your problem lies. One way to solve it would be to use the StringBuilder and the "append (String)". and it is adding everything together. Regards